# Sonar + jacoco agent code coverage for non-webservice modules

Tags: code-coverage, sonarqube, functional-testing, multi-module, jacoco

I'm trying to use JaCoCo agent for collecting FT code coverage of a web-site by adding `"-javaagent..."` to Jetty and running external Selenium tests (or, for example, manual testing).

At the end of testing I have results only for web-module, that was actually run in Jetty, but not for "core" modules (in the same project) being used in web-module. So, is there any ability to collect calls for **all** modules of the project?

Indeed, I now tried to start all project webservices (it has 5) with the same JaCoCo report destination (i.e. `/tmp/jacoco-res.exec`), `append=true` and ran:

```
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.jacoco.itReportPath=/tmp/jacoco-res.exec
```

So, sonar now used the **same** JaCoCo report file for every module in project and sonar shows tests coverage both for jetty-run and core modules.

Is this approach applicable and coverage results correct?

Answer (score 2):

I had a simular question that I posed on the [Sonar User forum](http://sonar.15.n6.nabble.com/IT-Testing-code-coverage-with-Jacoco-td5006840.html) a couple of days ago.

In short, your approach is correct and was also proposed by a Sonar consultant (as can be seen on the post).

- Perform a Sonar analyze on each Maven project.
- For each analysis, reuse the report and pass your JaCoCo report (using  -Dsonar.jacoco.itReportPath)
- Sonar will retrieve from this JaCoCo report
  the coverage data related to the Maven project being analyzed. (one of your core projects)
- Thus, for each Maven project, you'll get the coverage by your integration tests.
- Finally, to get the coverage of your webservice by your integration
  tests, you will have to use the Views plugin:
  http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/portfolio-management/
- Create a view that is an aggregation of all the Maven
  projects composing the webservice.
- Run a Sonar analysis of one of its
  Maven projects in order for Sonar to compute the view.
- On the view dashboard, you'll be able to get the code coverage
  of the webservice by your integration tests.